# Move to next step of loop on next run of script

Tags: loops, for-loop, while-loop

I need to create an auto generated email to tell me what backup tapes are to be loaded,
The script will run every Monday,
I have 3 sets of tapes Daily, Weekly & Monthly,
Daily and weekly tapes have 4 sets of tapes, Monthly have 12,
I was wondering if there is a way to setup a script so that it will move to the next set of tapes on each run,

ie 1st time the script runs it uses Daily set 1 & weekly set 1, on next run it uses Daily set 2 and weekly set 2, etc

Comment: Usually it's better idea to ask about specific language, the answer can differ radically...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to count how many times function has been invoked within the same process (same run of the application / script), you might simply use a `static` variable:

```
function countCalls() {
    static int countCalled = 0;
    countCalled++;
    // ... we know how many times this was called
}
```

If this is let's say cron job, you need to store this information in some persistant storage (write it into file, database etc.)

Comment: Thanks, I had thought I would have to write the count to a file, but was just checking if there was a way of not needing to,
Thanks for the help